# Deleting and re-inserting EmailMessage records along with Attachments

Tags: apex, batch

I have the following requierement: I need to recover some space in my org by taking all the EmailMessage records older than certain date and stripping the HTMLValue from them while keeping their association with Attachments.

According to what I investigated, the implementation I came up with is the following:

1. Querying all the EmailMessages older than the determined date and saving them in a variable.
2. Using those records querying all the ContentDocumentLink records related and saving them in a variable.
3. Deleting all the EmailMessage records and re-inserting them.
4. Re-inserting all the child ContentDocumentLink records but now associated to the new EmailMessage Id.

The way I'm relating EmailMessage records with their respective child ContentDocumentLink records is by using a Map `Map<EmailMessage, List<ContentDocumentLink>> emailsWithAttachments`. But soon I realized my mistake. At the very moment I try to insert the EmailMessage records, since the Ids are automatically added to the Map keys, I lose the associated values (ContentDocumentLink) because the key of the map was modified, and thus I'm unable to know which ContentDocumentLink records were associated to which EmailMessage records.

Below is a short snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
Map<EmailMessage, List<ContentDocumentLink>> emailsWithAttachments = new Map<EmailMessage, List<ContentDocumentLink>>();

...

//Delete original emails and insert versions without the HTML body
Database.delete(emails.values(), false);
List<EmailMessage> emailsToInsert = new List<EmailMessage>();
emailsToInsert.addAll(emailsWithAttachments.keySet());
Database.insert(emailsToInsert, false);
```

As of now the only way that I've been able to think of doing this it's by using a new custom field specifically for this prupose in the EmailMessage object. Something like "cleanupId" and make it a unique auto-number field, this way I'd have a constant value through the process that I could use to related the two objects.

But I have the feeling there's a better approach to this. Does anyone has any suggestion on what to try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible without having to create new fields but you're going to need to use a few more collections in your code to achieve this. I've attached a snippet below which should help you, but I've got a few comments to add more detail first.

First of all, you should use the old EmailMessage IDs as the key to your map, not the entire record. From here, you need to establish the link between the old EmailMessage IDs and the new records you're inserting by using a map of the Old ID and the new EmailMessage records (oldIDToNewMessageMap in the snippet below).

Once you've got both of these links, you can use the link between the old ID and the new records to then retrieve the associated ContentDocumentLinks to link to the new records.

```
List<EmailMessage> existingEmailMessages = new List<EmailMessage>();

//Get map of existing emailmessage and associated contentdocumentlinks
Map<Id, List<ContentDocumentLink>> emailIdswithAttachments = new Map<Id,List<ContentDocumentLink>>();

//Map to store the link between the old IDs and the new EmailMessage records
Map<Id,EmailMessage> oldIdToNewMessageMap = new Map<Id,EmailMessage>();

//Loop through and get a map of ID of old to ID of new.
for(EmailMessage existingMessage : existingEmailMessages){
    //Re-create existing message and add to Map using OLD Id
    EmailMessage newMessage = existingMessage.clone();
    oldIdToNewMessageMap.put(existingMessage.Id,newMessage);
}

//Insert new messages
Database.insert(oldIdToNewMessageMap.values());

//Now you can retrieve the ContentDocumentLinks via the emailIdsToAttachments map

for(Id oldId: oldIdToNewMessageMap.keySet()){
    List<ContentDocumentLink> documentsToLink = emailIdsToAttachments.get(oldId);
    //Add to list for processing
}
```